# convert into doctrine

Tags: mysql, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

```
SELECT id, forename, surname, created 
FROM name n 
WHERE created = (SELECT MAX(created) 
                          FROM name 
                          GROUP BY id 
                          HAVING id = n.id);
```

schema.yml:

```
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
  lcreated:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  forname/surname:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
```

I do have a extra table for forname and surname!

How can I convert this into doctrine 1.2?

Comment: Do you have schema.yml file? You should show it also

Comment: I updated my post with schema.yml

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('Name m')
  ->where('m.created = (SELECT MAX(gn.created) 
                          FROM Name gn
                          GROUP BY gn.id 
                          HAVING m.id = gn.id)');
```

[Link to the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#subqueries)